# Ensuring only synchronous pipes can be used in a function (disallowing asynchronous pipes)

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm working on an Angular app where data must be fetched from various sources (BehaviorSubjects with mapping pipe functions) in a synchronous way.

Until now, it has been done like this:

```
let magicNumber;
this.magicService.magicNumber$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => magicNumber = val));
```

etc. This ends up as a bunch of boilerplate, so I wanted to make a function to reduce this boilerplate significantly. However, the function I'm writing is only to be used for synchronous actions, but it accepts any kind of observable. For the time being, I'm trying to enforce this by throwing an error when a stream with asynchronity is passed to the function, and the current implementation looks like this:

```
export function select<T>(inStream: Observable<T>): T {
  let value: T;

  race(
    inStream,
    throwError(
      new Error(
        select.name +
          " expects a synchronous stream. Received an asynchronous stream."
      )
    )
  )
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(val => (value = val));

  return value;
}
```

Which allows me in the services to simply write:

```
const magicNumber = select(this.magicService.magicNumber$);
```

However, is there a more elegant way to enforce this? Preferrably I'd have some TypeScript trick that allows me to tell developers they're sending in the wrong type of Pipe as the argument during development, but I'm not sure if there's any way to recognize synchronous from asynchronous pipes just from type inference.

The problem now is that developers will not notice they've done something wrong until they're running the code and the code then crashing due to being passed an asynchronous stream.

For the sake of example, let's say I have three services, `userService`, `basketService`, `purchaseService`.

In `userService` I have the following:

```
userData$: BehaviorSubject<UserDataStore>;
...
userName$ = userData$.pipe(
  map(({ userName }) => userName));
```

likewise in basketService:

```
basketStore$: BehaviorSubject<BasketStore>;
...
basketContent$ = basketStore$.pipe(
  map(({ content }) => content));
```

In `purchaseService` I have a http-post method that with this implementation looks like this:

```
function purchase() {
  const userName = select(this.userService.userName$);
  const basketContent = select(this.basketService.basketContent$);
  this.http.post("http://niceUrl.com", {
    userName,
    basketContent
  }).subscribe(
    ReduceResponse
  )
```

(The pipes are simplified in this example; in practice they do contain retry code and error-catching etc.)

In other words, I'm talking about the procedure of collecting data from services already stored in BehaviorSubject *where I know the collecting will be synchronous*, and making a short-hand for this.

I know this code will only work when the streams are synchronous, so I want to discourage other programmers from trying to pass asynchronous streams into the method.

For comparison; this the example above before the `select` method was implemented:

```
function purchase() {
  let userName, basketContent;
  this.userService.userName$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => userName = val);
  this.basketService.basketContent$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => basketContent = val);
  this.http.post("http://niceUrl.com", {
    userName,
    basketContent
  }).subscribe(
    ReduceResponse
  )
```

PS! We're already practicing strictly asynchronous data update with OnPush in Component code, so comments about using RxJs asynchronously in components is not necessary

Comment: I'm not talking about the http-calls themselves. These are subscribtions on other services running in the frontend that has already collected data. RxJs pipes routed from BehaviorSubjects are synchronous by default, and it is for this purpose I want to create a simple select function to reduce boilerplate. I just want other developers to be careful and not believe that they can use this function with asynchronous pipes in synchronous code.

Comment: So where does the HTTP come in then? You mention it literally in the first sentence, so it seems important, and HTTP calls from the browser must be asynchronous to avoid the blocking behavior I mentioned. So can you clarify that (in the question)?

Comment: I updated the question with a more concrete example. The HTTP was mentioned as an example simply to illustrate that the function is called and will prepare with synchronous code before executing an asynchronous action. So the essence of the question is really making a short-hand for already synchronous code, but ensuring it is not used in an asynchronous way

Comment: But you don't actually need to do it at all. forkJoin the two service observables then flatMap the request from the resulting array of values.

Comment: @Lars Thanks. FWIW, I would try to shorten this, keeping primarily the latter parts you've added. I also suggest removing the HTTP part entirely, it's irrelevant to what you're asking (the fact that, `purchase` ends up doing an HTTP call doesn't  matter; what matters is that it uses `select` to get synchronously-available info). Fundamentally: You have observables you know will be synchronous, and you want a helper method to avoid boilerplate, and you want a good developer experience around the fact it can only accept synchronous observables. I hope someone has the answer! (Sadly, not I.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right. The HTTP part is irrelevant. I figured I'd include it to avoid people telling me to Angular the right way (in Component code, only using asynchronous streams), which we're already doing

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right it's not necessary. The reason it's being done is for readability and speed of development. In some services more than 20 data points must be collected from various services before sending http-requests, and wrapping everything in pipes makes the process of adding/removing things and keeping the types and order in place quite a hassle. The syntax I've introduced in this question reduces complexity and boilerplate significantly for these cases (from 60-70 lines of code to 20) and makes it easier to add/remove fields

Comment: It sounds like you have other problems to solve, then; think of this as the long parameter list smell. But encouraging people to treat observables as synchronous, or spend cycles figuring out which are and aren't (and debugging races when they're wrong), doesn't seem like a productive approach.

Comment: Indeed we have problems with long list of parameters, but in my clients codebase I only touch frontend code, so I have to work with the microservice apis I already have and need to make sure everything is prepared frontend for certain calls. The `select` function is only supposed to be used on selector pipes in services (essentially a pipe(map) on BehaviorSubjects that store data) that *will* be synchronous. I want to avoid other deverlopes accidentally sending asynchronous pipes into this method, as the context it is used is synchronous.